# Is it possible to search against a model and its association from the same text field using Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Profile model and a Publication model.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications
end

class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

I am using the [Ransack gem](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/) to perform searches on my Profile model:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Profile.search(params[:q])
    @profiles = @search.result
  end
end
```

profiles/index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name_cont, "Search term:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
<% end %>
```

This works as expected.

I am using the same form to perform searches on the associated Publication model.

As per [Ransack's documentation](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/#associations), I can do that like this:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Profile.search(params[:q]).includes(:publications)
    @profiles = @search.result
  end
end

<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :publications_title_cont, "Search term:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :publications_title_cont %>
<% end %>
```

This also works.

My question: is it possible to combine the two text fields? I would like to search against both the Profile model and the Publication model from the same text field.

I tried this:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name_cont_or_publications_title_cont, "Search term:" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_cont_or_publications_title_cont %>
<% end %>
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
undefined method `name_cont_or_publications_title_cont' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007f7688db1b80>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your error says `FIRST_name_cont_or_` . Looks like a typo in your original code although it's correctly written in the example...

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the example for the sake of the question. That was a typo. Fixed now :)

Comment: From memory I think you need to have the suffix at the end : `name_or_publications_title_cont` because you cannot combine differant suffixes anyway.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to break the 3000 points wall :)

Comment: Hopefully, that will help :)

Comment: ha ha that was a nice ride :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From memory I think you need to have the suffix only at the end because you cannot combine different suffixes anyway :

```
<%= f.text_field :name_or_publications_title_cont %>
```